# rails3, sessions and multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, models, controllers

I have a few models user, company, detail and I will like to save user_id, company_id and detail_id on a session so I can reused then later.

so question is how can I do this and should I put in on the application controller or leave it on each controller?

Answer (score 0):

If it is shared across many controllers, have it in the application controller. In order to store something in a session a simple `session[:key] = value` should work.

Comment: def create
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])
    @company.user_id = session[:user_id]
    session[:company_id] = @company.id
end ......this is what the company controller does when a user creates a new company, how can I make that session[:company_id] available on the application controller

Comment: You need to `@company.save` before you can access its `id`.